# What does an antenna "matching transformer labeled 75 ohm to 300 ohm" really mean?

Tags: antenna

Shouldn't it be the other way around? (300 ohms to 75 ohms)
300 ohms coming out from the antenna wires to 75 ohms coaxial cable?

Where does the 300 ohms comes from? is it because most antennas use wires that have 300 ohms impedance by default and you need this matching transformer to bring it down to 75 ohms.

What if the antenna is labeled 50 ohms? can we still use this matching transformer? or it is not necessary in such case.

Answer (score 3):

That's a lot of questions.

> Shouldn't it be the other way around? (300 ohms to 75 ohms) 300 ohms coming out from the antenna wires to 75 ohms coaxial cable?

Transformers are bidirectional; they don't care which way you hook them up. You could use one at each end of a piece of 75 Ω coax to connect a 300 Ω antenna to a 300 Ω TV. In fact, they first became common when people wanted to connect their 75 Ω CATV outlet to their 300 Ω TV input.

> Where does the 300 ohms comes from? is it because most antennas use wires that have 300 ohms impedance by default and you need this matching transformer to bring it down to 75 ohms.

The main element in a typical TV antenna is a "folded dipole" — a flattened loop of wire or tubing. Its natural impedance is close to 300 Ω.

> What if the antenna is labeled 50 ohms? can we still use this matching transformer? or it is not necessary in such case.

No, if you have a 50 Ω antenna, it will typically have a coaxial connector, and you wouldn't use a transformer. Although such an antenna would not be a good match for 75 Ω coax; you'd normally use 50 Ω coax with it.

Comment: Thank you @dave-tweed. I just wanted to give a little more context with the additional questions.It is clear now. Thanks Again!!!

Comment: More importantly, TV twin-lead has a 300 ohm characteristic impedance, and an antenna designed for it should have an impedance to match.

Comment: @TimWescott: The cable was designed to match the antenna, not the other way around.